# How can I use Sphinx with subpackages without duplicating everything?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have the following package structure as a minimal example (for convenience, all is uploaded [here](https://github.com/themightyoarfish/sphinx-mwe-so)):

```
.
├── sphinx
│   ├── build
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── source
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       └── train.rst
└── train
    ├── __init__.py
    └── train.py
```

When writing Python packages, one must specifiy the `__all__` constant in the `__init__.py` of any package in order for Sphinx to be able to map a reference such as `train.DatasetMeta` to `train.train.DatasetMeta` or similar. However, `sphinx-apidoc` generates the following sections for these packages:

```
train package
=============

Submodules
----------

train.train module
------------------

.. automodule:: train.train
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:


Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: train
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

Which duplicates the entire documentation as it contains `.. automodule:: module.file` as well as `.. automodule:: module`, which refer to the same thing. Removing either of these sections results in undefined reference warnings (turned into errors when using `-n` to `SPHINXOPTS`).

```
sphinx_test/train/train.py:docstring of train.DatasetMeta:1:py:class reference target not found: train.train.DatasetMeta
```

How can I solve this?

**train/train.py**

```
from collections import namedtuple


class DatasetMeta(namedtuple('DatasetMeta', ['dataset', 'num_classes', 'shape'])):
    @property
    def size(self):
        '''int: Number of examples in the dataset'''
        return self.shape[0]
```

**train/__init__.py**

```
from .train import *

__all__ = ['DatasetMeta']
```

**sphinx/source/conf.py**

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))


project = 'test'
copyright = ''
author = ''

version = ''
release = '0'

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
]

source_suffix = '.rst'
master_doc = 'index'
```

I just cannot figure out what the logic is here.

Comment: Deleting the `train.train` block from the generated Sphinx doc seems to be the easiest solution to me.  What "undefined reference warnings" are you getting when you do this?

Comment: As I said, I cannot delete this since I get `sphinx_test/train/train.py:docstring of train.DatasetMeta:1:py:class reference target not found: train.train.DatasetMeta` warnings. I'm using nitpicky mode so this is an error, and regardless I would like this solved properly.

Comment: The problem appears to be due in part to the use of `:show-inheritance:` with a class that inherits from a `namedtuple`; deleting the `:show-inheritance:` line gets the docs to build, but I don't know how acceptable this is.

Comment: I assume it's the same for every class which inherits from a class living in a subpackage.

Comment: What version of Sphinx do you use? Have you seen https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4609? Your error message looks just as bogus as the ones in that bug report.

Comment: I've seen the issue, and of course i could circumvent the warning, but that would mean not getting a hyperlink for the reference.

Comment: *"not getting a hyperlink for the reference"*. I don't understand. For what reference do you expect a hyperlink?

Comment: The one generating the warning/error from the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. What code or RST markup in your project are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, was confused. Actually it probably doesn't generate a link in this case, since the error occurs simply by using `.. automodule` in the context of inheritance. But if I were to use :class:`train.DatasetMeta` somewhere else, i would have the problem that i get this error when deleting one of the sections, so I'd have to put that into the ignore list and won't get a link for it.

Comment: This is not an issue with Sphinx - it is an issue with the `DatasetMeta` class declaration. You declare a class named `DatasetMeta` in `DatasetMeta` inheritance list, so `DatasetMeta.__bases__` will contain `train.train.DatasetMeta` - not your class, but the `namedtuple` happening to have the same name. This is the inheritance Sphinx picks up.

Comment: Depending on what Python version you use: if it's Python 3.6, I'd suggest subclassing `typing.NamedTuple` and using [instance variable annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations) so you have proper subclassing from stdlib's `tuple`. Or even better, use [dataclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) if you're targeting Python 3.7.

Comment: @hoefling Nice, that seems to be the problem, makes sense kinda.

Comment: However, I still meet this problem if I define a class in a submodule and inherit from it in the same submodule. There should be a way around this.

Comment: Within the same file I can explicitly assing the `__module__` attribute for the class in question, but that fails if I then inherit from that class in another submodule.

Comment: @oarfish It depends on what end result you want to achieve. If you want to keep the inheritance from `namedtuple` as shown in your question, I would go with turning the `show-inheritance` option off for the `DatasetMeta` class as it's basically useless and doesn't reflect the actual codebase (you can't subclass the `DatasetMeta` namedtuple anyway, so why having it documented in the first place?). You can turn `show-inheritance` off dynamically in the `conf.py` using events. If you need an example for that, I will write an answer with working code.

Comment: In general I'd like all documentation to use the shorthand name, i.e. `train` instead of `train.train` in this example. For this specific class I could turn off displaying inheritance, but imagine the module defines a class which I inherit from often (which happens in my original code I derived this example from). That would be a hierarchy useful to document, so I'd rather not turn off `:show-inheritance:` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

One thing we can do to make the situation simpler is a minor rename:

```
class DatasetMeta(namedtuple('DatasetMetaBase', ['dataset', 'num_classes', 'shape'])):
```

which should make it obvious that the missing reference is `train.train.DatasetMetaBase` when you remove the `train.train` block from the rst file generated by `sphinx-apidoc`. The documentation for `train.DatasetMeta` and `train.train.DatasetMeta` is going to refer to `train.train.DatasetMetaBase`; I don't know way to hack around that without patching autodoc or adding your own directives.

From here, I see a few options:

(1) Move `DatasetMetaBase` to a different module that is not imported in `__init__.py`. For example

```
from .abstract import DatasetMetaBase
class DatasetMeta(DatasetMetaBase):
```

That way the autodoc for `DatasetMeta` refers to `train.abstract.DatasetMetaBase`, which should be a unique ref in your case.

(2) Create a separate rst file (say, `hidden.rst`) that renders the docs for `train.train.DatasetMetaBase`, but hidden from the main rst.

```
# hidden.rst
.. autodata:: train.train.DatasetMetaBase
```

That should be enough to add `train.train.DatasetMetaBase` to sphinx and resolve the `class reference target not found` warning.